# Javascript syntax error on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following bit of code which adjusts the headers of some parsed data:

```
    var parsedData = transposed.map(row =>
        row.reduce((acc, col, ind) => {
            acc[headers[ind]] = col;
            return acc;
        }, { }));
```

The code works fine on Chrome/Edge/Firefox but fails on Internet Explorer saying there's a syntax error at: **row =>**.

I'm unable to determine where the syntax error is being thrown - I'm relatively new to javascript's map function so I may be missing something. Where in the above code snippet is the syntax error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrow functions are a core part of the ES6 language feature set.

Those are not directly supported in IE, you need to transpile your code first.

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is the go-to transpiler for ES6.

Answer (score 3):

IE is old and does not understand the arrow function syntax.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

you might need to use the old anonymous function to make it compatible with IE  <strike>or if polyfill exists, use those.</strike>  or use transpilers (such as Babel) to transpile it to es5.

example of old annonymous function:

```
transposed.map(function(row){
        row.reduce((acc, col, ind) => {
            acc[headers[ind]] = col;
            return acc;
   }, { });
});
```

but remember, you will lose scope of the outside `this`

Comment: Also, there's two arrow functions in OP's example, you only translated the outer one :)